# How to convert nano second epoch timestamp to readable format

Tags: c++, unix-timestamp

I have an long long integer that represents an epoch timestamp with nanosecond precision, I would like to convert it into human readable timestamp such as date-hh:mm:ss

I tried to use static cast and directly cast this integer to time_t format, and is intended to use localtime to format it, but does not success.

From documentation it appears that time_ts is a 32 bit integer, which means is not large enough to read my timestamp. What's best way to format my timestamp to human readable format ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
   time_t now = time(NULL);
   long long int ts = 1561402947698860015;

   time_t t = static_cast<time_t>(ts);
   std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&t))
          << t << " seconds since the Epoch\n";
   std::cout<<"done"<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should try a look at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: Another handy link: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date Mr. Hinnant has solved most of the formatting problems you are going to run into.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work if you divide to convert into seconds (as commented by user4581301):

```
long long int ts = 1561402947698860015 / 1000000000;
```

But also, instead of using:

```
std::asctime(std::localtime(&t))
```

you can just use the following to get the same result:

```
ctime(&t)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

A simple cast won't know it needs to shift the number's scaling from nanos to seconds (as seconds are what's almost always the increment used by `time_t`). To the compiler it's just one integer being assigned to another integer, maybe even the same type. if you have a time in nanoseconds and you want to use `time_t` you'll probably need to divide by 1,000,000,000 to convert your stamp into seconds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

constexpr long long int nanos_to_seconds = 1000000000; // conversion factor
constexpr long long int nanos_to_milis = 1000000;

int main()
{
   time_t now = time(NULL);
   long long int ts = 1561402947698860015;

   time_t t = static_cast<time_t>(ts/nanos_to_seconds);
                                  //^ change here
   long long int milis = ts % nanos_to_seconds / nanos_to_millis; // compute milliseconds
   std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&t))
             << t << "." << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << millis
             << " seconds since the Epoch\n";
   std::cout<<"done"<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

## Option 2

As of C++11, C++ has built in support for nanosecond timestamps in [the `<chrono>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). Combine this with [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) and all of your formatting concerns are taken care of along with getting your code ready for C++20. This is worth looking into. It does not solve your current problem right out of the box, but can be used to replace the problem so that it is less annoying in the future.

## Side note:

These days `time_t` is usually a 64 bit count of seconds. The 32 bit counter is going to roll in another 20 years or so, so rather than have to put up with a Y2038 bug at the last minute, a move to a much larger number was started a few decades ago.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Is it possible to achieve higher precision, say, get the millisecond part via localtime ? The static_cast<time_t> seems to truncate timestamp to second, and thus lose precision.

Comment: `time_t` is (typically) nothing but a 64 bit signed integer counting seconds. You cannot get fractional seconds with that. If you want fractional seconds, you can tack on `ts%nanos_to_seconds` with appropriate zero padding, but it's sounding more like you want to explore Option 2. See update to answer.

Comment: Answer concerning higher precision:  Yes with option 2:  `1561402947698860015` formats to `2019-06-24 15:02:27.698860015` in my local time zone.  If you only want millisecond precision, that is easily truncated to as well.